# install sqlite3 dev and other packages in centos

Tags: linux, sqlite, centos, yum

I am trying to install sqlite dev and other libraries in a centos machine with cpanel, to be able to compile an application.
I am more acquainted with debian than centos, and I know the libraries I need are:

```
libsqlite3-dev
libkrb5-dev
libssl-dev
libcurl3-dev
libboost-all-dev
```

For what I could find online, the corresponding package in centos for `libsqlite3-dev` is `sqlite-dev`.

However, when I run `yum install sqlite-devel` I get the following message:

```
No package sqlite-devel available
```

I don't know if this is related to cpanel, if repositories are missing from the installation, and since my experience with yum is far lesser than with apt, I am quite lost here.

I have searched for the package `yum search sqlite` and all I get is this:

```
cpanel-perl-522-DBD-SQLite.x86_64 : CPAN module - Self Contained SQLite RDBMS in a DBI Driver
cpanel-perl-522-DBD-SQLite2.x86_64 : CPAN module - Self Contained RDBMS in a DBI Driver (sqlite 2.x)
ea-apr-util-sqlite.x86_64 : APR utility library SQLite DBD driver
freeradius-sqlite.x86_64 : SQLite support for freeradius
golang-googlecode-sqlite-devel.x86_64 : Trivial sqlite3 binding for Go
perl-DBD-SQLite.x86_64 : SQLite DBI Driver
cpanel-perl-522-CPAN-SQLite.x86_64 : CPAN module - maintain and search a minimal CPAN database
sqlite.x86_64 : Library that implements an embeddable SQL database engine
```

Also, this is the output of `yum repolist`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.100.0.204
 * base: repo.us.bigstepcloud.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.eboundhost.com
 * updates: centos.firehosted.com
repo id                                                                                            repo name                                                                                                                         status
EA4/7/x86_64                                                                                       EA4 ( EasyApache 4 )                                                                                                                  23703
base/7/x86_64                                                                                      CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                                     9319+44
epel/x86_64                                                                                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                    10524+779
extras/7/x86_64                                                                                    CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                                       266
updates/7/x86_64                                                                                   CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                                     1086
repolist: 44898
```

As an additional detail, this server is not managed or owned by me, so I don't know much information about it.

What I know is that I have several centos + cpanel servers, and I just did a `yum search sqlite-devel` in another one, and it shows the package in the base repo.

I have also noticed that the offending server is not updated. Can this be a reason?

Any other hints?

Comment: are there any `exclude` directives in `/etc/yum.conf` or in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Late response, but perhaps this might help others who eventually stumble on this question looking for the same answer.

The sqlite3 development package can be found in the epel repo. [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Easy to install on CentOS -> yum install epel-release

`$ yum list | grep sqlite

libsqlite3x-devel.x86_64                20071018-20.el7                @epel`

Similar list/grep can be done for the other libraries you are looking to install, although the names are most likely just slightly different (list edited for clarity).

`$ yum list | grep boost

boost-devel.x86_64                      1.53.0-26.el7                  base`

Comment: On my system, it was called "sqlite-devel.x86_64" .  The desciption said it was the drivers for sqlite3.

Comment: You can pass filtering arguments to `yum list` as in: `yum list '*sqlite*'`

Comment: @MikePone: you don't need the '.x86_64' - yum installs whatever's relevant for your system. So just `yum install sqlite-devel`

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I had to do `yum install libsqlite3x-devel.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

For Centos and Fedora with dnf package manager you can use "dnf search" followed  by a keyword to search, in this case "sqlite"

```
dnf search sqlite | grep devel
```

For RPM based systems(Redhat / CentOS / Fedora) "**-devel**" is the suffice used to identify package with development files, usually refered as development tools, so I use grep to filter the result list.

These commands return me:

```
qlite-devel.x86_64 : Development tools for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine
```

If you don't see the 3 explicit neither in the name or description you can get the info that confirm you this with "dnf info" followed by the package name:

```
dnf info sqlite-devel
```

which return more info like the version, license, etc.

**Note:**

Of course for Fedora is possible that sqlite package comes available due to the fact that fedora has it in its repo otherwise you would have to enable Epel repository as described by Eric in [Epel](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/)

References:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Displaying_Package_Information.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager