# configure error: Package requirements (sqlite3 > 3.7.4) were not met

Tags: php, sqlite, centos7

I'm trying to install php on Centos 7 following instructions from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.nginx.php.
My nginx version: nginx/1.19.0

I downloaded php-7.4.6.tar.gz from https://www.php.net/downloads 
but 
at the step:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --with-mysqli
```

I got this error:

```
checking for sqlite3 > 3.7.4... no
configure: error: Package requirements (sqlite3 > 3.7.4) were not met:

No package 'sqlite3' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SQLITE_CFLAGS
and SQLITE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I do have sqlite3 up and running:

```
# sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.17
```

So, how should I set the environment variable (in configure file?)?
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to install `sqlite-devel` (https://pkgs.org/download/sqlite-devel).

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Could you put it in a post so that I could vote your answer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To compile from source, dependencies need to be available as a linkable library (and sometimes headers which the new program uses for building). `-devel` packages install these libraries, so to build PHP from source with SQLite support, you need to install `sqlite-devel`.

If you have Ubuntu >= 20.04, install this package `libsqlite3-dev` to satisfy the dev dependency/package requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I did a "yum install sqlite-devel" and solved the issue.

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 20.04,  install this package `libsqlite3-dev` to satisfy the dev dependency/package requirements.

Answer (score 18):

`sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev` will work. To know which libraries to install you may find `apt search sqlite3` useful.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libonig-dev libreadline-dev libtidy-dev libxslt-dev libzip-dev
```

Comment: This one. I had to do `libpng-dev` as well (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu21.04 I needed to use `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: Please make more obvious the additional insight your answer provides in comparison to the existing and upvoted answer by pateheo. Also please have a look at [answer] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` works for ubuntu.

Comment: This is partially correct. The installation of sqlite3 (developing one) is needed, but for CentOS 7 not for Ubuntu. Here is the existing answer on the question how to install sqlite3 on CentOs 7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669368/install-sqlite3-dev-and-other-packages-in-centos

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 I had the same problem after installing :-

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

To get round this :-

```
sudo find / -name sqlite3.pc
```

Then add the folder that contains that file to :-

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

Comment: I was missing `libsqlite3-dev` package, since I needed it to compile another program.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for Alpine Linux

`pkg add sqlite-dev`