# Can't build PHP 8.0.19 from source - No package 'sqlite3' found

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu

Im on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

---

I try to build PHP 8.0.19 from source. I've downloaded it from [here](https://www.php.net/downloads.php).

I get this after I call `./configure`

```
checking for sqlite3 > 3.7.4... no
configure: error: Package requirements (sqlite3 > 3.7.4) were not met:

No package 'sqlite3' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SQLITE_CFLAGS
and SQLITE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Output of `sqlite3 --version`:

```
3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1
```

So I tried to configure without sqlite3

```
./configure --without-sqlite3
```

But I still get the same error.

If I try to install **sqlite3** with `apt-get update && apt-get install sqlite3` I get:

```
sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.37.2-2).
```

---

I tried to build the latest sqlite3 version from source, but the latest version I found is `3.38.5.`

https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had to install `libsqlite3-dev`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155296/4684797